# sed and awk in sh script not replacing text

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, find, replace

The desired work to find a string, and replace to another (all occurrencies), and rewrite/update the file too.

The file is an `pbxproj` file. [I linked a sample of this file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/ios-sample-blender/blob/master/Blender.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj)

sample of the file *(please note this file is too huge to share a non working sample here. You can check the link before)*:

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    archiveVersion = 1;
    classes = {
    };
    objectVersion = 46;
    objects = {

/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
        4D1498151706397100876A74 /* Icon.png in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 4D1498141706397100876A74 /* Icon.png */; };
        4D1498171706397300876A74 /* Icon@2x.png in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 4D1498161706397300876A74 /* Icon@2x.png */; };
        F8F1FD8E1705DF6A0012AA85 /* UIKit.framework in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FD8D1705DF6A0012AA85 /* UIKit.framework */; };
        F8F1FD901705DF6A0012AA85 /* Foundation.framework in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FD8F1705DF6A0012AA85 /* Foundation.framework */; };
        F8F1FD921705DF6A0012AA85 /* CoreGraphics.framework in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FD911705DF6A0012AA85 /* CoreGraphics.framework */; };
        F8F1FDB61705DF6A0012AA85 /* UIKit.framework in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FD8D1705DF6A0012AA85 /* UIKit.framework */; };
        F8F1FDB71705DF6A0012AA85 /* Foundation.framework in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FD8F1705DF6A0012AA85 /* Foundation.framework */; };
        F8F1FDF5170609D20012AA85 /* UIImage+TBTint.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDDD170609D20012AA85 /* UIImage+TBTint.m */; };
        F8F1FDF6170609D20012AA85 /* TBBAppDelegate.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDE0170609D20012AA85 /* TBBAppDelegate.m */; };
        F8F1FDF7170609D20012AA85 /* TBBFlatImageViewController.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDE2170609D20012AA85 /* TBBFlatImageViewController.m */; };
        F8F1FDF8170609D20012AA85 /* TBBGradientImageViewController.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDE4170609D20012AA85 /* TBBGradientImageViewController.m */; };
        F8F1FDF9170609D20012AA85 /* TBBMasterViewController.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDE6170609D20012AA85 /* TBBMasterViewController.m */; };
        F8F1FDFB170609D20012AA85 /* Default-568h@2x.png in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDEA170609D20012AA85 /* Default-568h@2x.png */; };
        F8F1FDFC170609D20012AA85 /* Default.png in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDEB170609D20012AA85 /* Default.png */; };
        F8F1FDFD170609D20012AA85 /* Default@2x.png in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDEC170609D20012AA85 /* Default@2x.png */; };
        F8F1FDFE170609D20012AA85 /* MainStoryboard.storyboard in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = F8F1FDED170609D20012AA85 /* MainStoryboard.storyboard */; };
.
.
.
.
.
        44567HGFGHJK456GH44GHJK /* Debug */ = {
            .
            .
            .
            buildSettings = {
                ...
                FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                    "$(inherited)",
                    "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter",
                );
                INFOPLIST_FILE = Runner/Info.plist;
                IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0;
                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks";
                LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                    "$(inherited)",
                    "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter",
                );
                MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.1;
```

```
#!/bin/sh

cpath=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && printf '%s\n' "$(pwd -P)/")
xcodePath="${cpath}ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"

sed -i -e 's/MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.1/MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.2/g' xcodePath

# or tried with awk too

# awk '{gsub("MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.1","MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.2"); print}' xcodePath
```

When its done I checked the file, and nothing changed. No error, no warning!
Is there any way to fix?

Comment: Without knowing the file contents it is hard to tell. Please provide some relevant lines. Note, that `.` is a special character in regex and needs escaping, otherwise you will also match e.g. `MARKETING_VERSION = 1.101`.

Comment: ok, i edited my question, and linked a sample file

Comment: Please provide some minimal useful not-working sample in the question body, together with the expected output. Anyways, there is no string `MARKETING_VERSION` in that file.

Comment: ok, thx, updated my question

Comment: Your linked and your posted sample do not match. There is no `MARKETING_VERSION` in the linked file. Your posted sample is not a subset of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script fails to expand the variable xcodepath using '$'.  Like:

```
sed -i -e 's/MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.1/MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.2/g' "$xcodePath"
```

Comment: Thx, that was the problem.

Comment: OP should double-quote the variable too -= `"$xcodePath"`, in case it contains whitespace or other annoying characters.   There are very few cases where it is useful or desirable to not quote a variable when it is used (and many cases where failing to quote a variable can cause harm), so the rule of thumb is: unless you know for sure you don't want it quoted AND you know exactly **why** you don't want it quoted in this particular instance, then always quote variables when you use them.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of a variable in shell you prefix it with `$` (and quote it unless you have a very specific need to not quote it) so `xcodePath` needs to be `"$xcodePath"`.

You also need to escape the `.` metachars and anchor the regexp otherwise you would undesirably change `MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.10` or `MARKETING_VERSION = 12151`, for example, to `MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.2`. You also don't need to repeat the string `MARKETING_VERSION = 1.1.` just to change the final digit from 1 to 2, just use a capture group.

```
sed -Ei 's/(\<MARKETING_VERSION = 1\.1\.)1;/\12;/' "$xcodePath"
```

You were already using GNU sed for `-i` so I added `-E` just so we don't need to escape the parentheses in the capture group.